# how the second activity crash?

Tags: java, android, layout

i just want to fill some infos in the activitymain and then pass an intent to a second activity, at the first it works perfect but when i add some xml layout, when running the app on device and pass the intent it crashes

the main activity

```
public void move(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormActivity.class);
    EditText name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText animal = findViewById(R.id.animal);
    String n = name.getText().toString();
    String a = animal.getText().toString();


    if (n.isEmpty() || a.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "nom ou animal est vide !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        i.putExtra("KEY_Name", name.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("KEY_Animal", animal.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
// and the formactivity or the second

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    TextView Text1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);
    TextView Text2 = findViewById(R.id.t2);

    String name = i.getStringExtra("KEY_Name");
    String animal = i.getStringExtra("KEY_Animal");

    Text1.setText(name);
    Text2.setText(animal);

}
```

// XML file for activity_main it works perfect

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/dog" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="-2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.075" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    style="@style/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="-2"
        android:shadowDy="-2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="3dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="@string/ex_name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linear2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    style="@style/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="-2"
        android:shadowDy="-2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="@string/pet"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="3dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/animal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="@string/ex_animal"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:onClick="move"
    android:text="Suivant"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.096"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.344" />
```

// the activity_form or second that crashes

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/sheep" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/title" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_fluid"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Hello freind!"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="oh, puppy!"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="comment Aidez-Vous ?" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="mon Chat souffre de fièvre"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="6"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/logo"
        android:text="envoyer"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the logcat

```
10-09 18:03:08.327 29724-29724/com.example.android.workingproject  W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080946 (t=7 e=2374) (error -75)
10-09 18:04:20.737 29724-29724/com.example.android.workingproject W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080946 (t=7 e=2374) (error -75)
10-09 18:04:21.538 29724-29724/com.example.android.workingproject E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 343944636 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 52MB until OOM"
10-09 18:04:21.608 29724-29724/com.example.android.workingproject E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 343944636 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 52MB until OOM"
10-09 18:04:21.628 29724-29724/com.example.android.workingproject E/art: li.han, Prepare to dump hprof for OOM Error !
    li.han, Directory [/data/log] could not be write !
10-09 18:04:21.638 29724-29724/com.example.android.workingproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.workingproject, PID: 29724
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 343944636 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 52MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:837)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:656)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1037)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4056)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3779)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.android.workingproject.FormActivity.onCreate(FormActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: do you mean the logcat in android studio

Comment: Yes. Filter by "Error" and you'll see the stracktrace.

Comment: ah okey sorry i'll update it

Comment: You have a image as background on your second activity? If yes, try remove them. Sometimes it cause crash by "out of memory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of the drawables referenced in your second XML file is too big.

Check the following drawables and resize them:

- sheep
- title
- list_fluid

PNGs generally don't need to be very large. Keep them below 1600x1600 if you can, preferably 800x800.

Comment: it works i got the same problem before 3 months, thank you so much(;